# powershell start-process command with spaces

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work in Windows 10?

```
{start-process powershell 'start-process c:\windows\syswow64\mmc.exe """c:\path\to\my\administrative tool\console1.msc""" -verb runas' -credential domain\user}
```

It was working just fine and dandy under Windows 8.1. However, after moving to Windows 10 this morning, the code errors out at the space in the path to console1.msc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the actual error output. And also tell us what you've already tried (and what the results were).

Comment: Let me get it right, you are running powershell (32/64bit) start powershell to start 32bit mmc with admin rights and different credentials?

Comment: - Issue command
- Enter credentials at PowerShell credential request
- Answer yes to UAC prompt

Receive following error:

----------------------------
Microsoft Management Console
----------------------------
MMC cannot open the file
C:\path\to\my\administrative.
This may be because the file does not exist, is not an MMC console, or was created by a later version of MMC. This may also be because you do not have sufficient access rights to the file.
----------------------------
[OK]
----------------------------So, it is not handling the space in the path correctly. Quotes issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that each step along the way of launching a PowerShell process from a PowerShell process to launch MMC eats up some double-quotes to guard against spaces. (Arguments to PowerShell itself can require escaping as well.) Therefore, you need to escape those quotes further. In fact, you need nine - count them, *nine* - double-quote characters on each side:

```
start-process powershell 'start-process c:\windows\syswow64\mmc.exe """""""""c:\administrative tool\console1.msc""""""""" -verb runas' -credential domain\user
```

Comment: That did it! I went as far out as 6, but who would've thought so many were needed. Thank you!!!

Comment: """""""""i n c r e d i b l e"""""""""